# How to render angular components in a table layout dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-components

Let's say a web request is made and it returns a list of items of a kind. I have an Angular component designed to render the specified kind of data. Now, how to initialize component instances to each of the item obtained from the web request and render it in a table format?

I failed to do it myself and also to obtain any useful info in web. Could you please help?
Thanks in advance!

```
  @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container;

  constructor(public resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  clicked(event) {
    const addressFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AddressComponent);
    const addressRef = this.container.createComponent(addressFactory);
    addressRef.instance.title = 'Home';
   }
```

I could do this. But 'container' reference will become hardcoded. I want to dynamically create a  add a  for each item returned and insert the populated AddressComponent inside that . I can't hardcode reference as my 's are dynamic.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can try and see where it's gone wrong. It should help explain what you're trying to achieve as well

Comment: More details please.

Comment: Do you want to render a component inside each row dynamically?

Comment: Yes. That correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind! I found the answer after deep googling!

https://medium.com/@caroso1222/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6

```
import {
    Injectable,
    Injector,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    EmbeddedViewRef,
    ApplicationRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DomService {

  constructor(
      private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
      private appRef: ApplicationRef,
      private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  appendComponentToBody(component: any) {
    // 1. Create a component reference from the component 
    const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(component)
      .create(this.injector);

    // 2. Attach component to the appRef so that it's inside the ng component tree
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    // 3. Get DOM element from component
    const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    // 4. Append DOM element to the body
    document.body.appendChild(domElem);

    // 5. Wait some time and remove it from the component tree and from the DOM
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
        componentRef.destroy();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: A ton thanks. I was hitting my head for this from the past 2 days. This really unblocked me.